# Must a set $B$ of finite perimeter of nonzero measure contain interior points?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Here is a follow-up questions to [Must a Borel set B of nonzero measure contain an interval as a subset?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341280/must-a-borel-set-b-of-nonzero-measure-contain-an-interval-as-a-subset)?

The answer to the original question is NO. For example, $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ or the fat cantor set.

I apply the definition of sets of finite perimeter from Maggi's book.

A Lebesgue measurable set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set of locally finite perimeter in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if for every compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, we have
$$\sup\left\{\int_E \mathrm{div} T(x)\mathrm{d}x: T\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n),\mathrm{spt} T\subset K, \sup|T|\leqslant 1\right\}<\infty$$

If the above quantity is bounded independent of $K$, we say $E$ is a set of finite perimeter.

Comment: Is this notion of perimeter infinitely subadditive? If you change the perimeter by the $n - 1$-Hausdorff measure the answer is negative I think (just take a big ball B, and remove each ball of the for $B_{3^{-n}}(q_n)$ where $q_n$ is an enumeration of the rational in $B$).